# office 365 mail unable to open notes Link which

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Case happen: 
User From Notes Mail change to Office 365, their email contain Lotus notes link(Document link) which cannot be accessible.

Call rtBody.Appenddoclink(LateInVw, "", "Click to view your attendance today") ,
I put the "NotesView"into the email body which not show up on office 365. May i know office 365 have any way to identify this is notes Client application and try to open the notes application of that view?

```
Dim tdy As Variant
Sub Initialize()
Print"Agent:Request for LateIn Reason started running at " & DateValue(Now()) & "," + TimeValue(Now())
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    Dim ss As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim LateInVw As NotesView
    Dim LateInDocs As NotesViewEntryCollection
    Dim LateEntry As NotesViewEntry
    Dim LateDoc As NotesDocument
    Dim StaffVw As NotesView, StaffDoc As NotesDocument
    Dim AttVw As NotesView, Attdoc As notesdocument
    Dim MailDoc As NotesDocument
    Dim rtBody As NotesRichTextItem

    Set db=ss.Currentdatabase
    Set LateInVw=db.getview("($Today Not Alerted Late-In Time Records)")
    Set StaffVw=db.getview("($Active Staff by ID)")
    Set AttVw = db.Getview("($Effective Attendance Setting By ID)")
    tdy=Datevalue(Now)

    'get all time records for today
    Set LateInDocs=LateInVw.Allentries
    Set lateEntry=LateInDocs.getfirstentry
    Do While Not LateEntry Is Nothing
        Set LateDoc=LateEntry.Document
        Set Attdoc=Attvw.Getdocumentbykey(LateDoc.TStaffID(0), True)
        If Attdoc.LateAtt(0)="Yes" Then
            If Not ApprovedLateIn(LateDoc, LateDoc.TAmend(0), False) Then
                'get staff mail
                Set staffDoc=StaffVw.Getdocumentbykey(LateDoc.TStaffID(0), True)
                If Not staffdoc Is Nothing Then
                    'send email with link to main menu
                    email$=staffDoc.email(0)
                    Set Maildoc=New NotesDocument(db)
                    maildoc.Sendto=email$
                    maildoc.Subject="Smartcard Attendance System: Late-In Notification for " +Format$(LateDoc.TDate(0),"dd/mm/yyyy")
                    Set rtBody=New NotesRichTextItem(maildoc, "Body")
                    Call rtBody.appendtext(" Dear"+" "+ staffDoc.StaffName(0)+",")
                    Call rtBody.AddNewline(2)
                    Call rtBody.appendtext("You clocked in to work today at "+lateDoc.TAmend(0)+". Please click on the link below to submit your reason for the late attendance. Thank You!")
                    Call rtBody.Addnewline(1)
                    Call rtBody.Appenddoclink(LateInVw, "", "Click to view your attendance today")
                    Call rtBody.Addnewline(2)
                    Call rtBody.Appendtext("***If the box to key in the late-in reason does not appear, kindly use the 'History Attendance' to key-in instead.")
                    maildoc.send(False)
                End If
            End If 
            'End If 'check late-in on/off in attendance settings
            LateDoc.LateInAlert="Send"
            Call LateDoc.save(True,False)
        End If 'check late-in on/off in attendance settings
        Set LateEntry=LateInDocs.Getnextentry(LateEntry)
    Loop
Print"Agent:Request for LateIn Reason ended running at " & DateValue(Now()) & "," + TimeValue(Now())
    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    Print "Got error " & Error$ & " on line " & CStr(Erl)
    Resume next
Print"Agent:Request for LateIn Reason ended running at " & DateValue(Now()) & "," + TimeValue(Now())
End Sub
```

[image]

This is my sample rewrite code as Mime format...

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim ss As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim vw As NotesView
    'Dim Doc As NotesViewEntryCollection

    Dim LateInVw As NotesView
    Dim Ec As NotesViewEntryCollection
    Dim Entry As NotesViewEntry
    Dim Doc As NotesDocument

    Dim MailDoc As NotesDocument
    Dim rtBody As NotesRichTextItem

    Set db=ss.Currentdatabase
    Set vw=db.getview("(test send mail)")
    tdy=DateValue(Now)


    %Rem
    Set replydoc = db.Createdocument()
    Call replydoc.Replaceitemvalue("Form", "Memo")
    Call replydoc.Replaceitemvalue("Subject", "Pre-check Passed - " + apptitle)
    Call replydoc.Replaceitemvalue("SendTo", indoc.From(0))
    Call replydoc.Replaceitemvalue("BlindCopyTo", mailinadd)
    Set body = replydoc.Createmimeentity
    %End Rem    
    Set EC = vw.Allentries
    Set Entry=Ec.getfirstentry
    Do While Not Entry Is Nothing
        Set Doc = Entry.Document

        email$="chee111385@gmail.com"
        Set Maildoc= db.Createdocument()
        Call Maildoc.Replaceitemvalue("Form", "Memo")
        Call Maildoc.Replaceitemvalue("Subject", "Test Send Mail, Mime Format")
        Call Maildoc.Replaceitemvalue("SendTo",email$)
        Set body = Maildoc.Createmimeentity

        ss.Convertmime = False 
        Set stream = ss.Createstream()

        stream.Writetext(|<html><body>|)
        stream.Writetext(|<p>Dear Sir, | + |,</p>|)
        stream.Writetext(|<p>This is a testing mail. Thanks You!<br>| + |</p>|)
        stream.Writetext(|<p>|+|Notes://Mulu/482577AE00260EC5/|+ +Doc.Universalid+|</p>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|</body></html>|)

        Call body.Setcontentfromtext(stream, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 1725)
        Call maildoc.Send(False)
        ss.Convertmime = True 

        Set Entry = EC.Getnextentry(Entry)
    Loop

End Sub
```

I not sure how to just open notes document directly...as everytime i click the link it go to the frameset itself...which is not correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about just this one application, then what you need to do is learn about notes:// URLs, which you can [read about here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/notes-urls). You just need to change your code to generate a correctly formatted URL for the view, either instead of or in addition to the doclink. When the user clicks the notes:// URL, the Notes client will open and take the user to the view.

If, however, you actually have lots of applications that send doclinks to users, than you may want to look for a solution that installs on your Domino server and handles this automatically for all the applications without you having to change any code. A company called Genii Software has a product called CoExLinks Fidelity that does this.

Comment: You are pointing me to a correct way! but i not sure few thing can you give me some advice on it! will post some image!